# Laravel 5 new custom message in lang folder

Tags: laravel, message, status, lang

That later different languages ​​can be used, i would like want to save status and success messages in a central file and output them by the respective controller. Currently I'm still doing that in each controller extra.

At the moment:

```
return back()->with('status', 'Thanks for contacting us!');
```

Comment: As much as I can understand why you're wanting to do this, will this not make future message updates very puzzling as you won't fully register which success message etc you're editing..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Manually insert all the messages in directory `resources > lang > en > messages.php`  , or create any other language folder you might want.

And then you can use it with this `Lang::get('messages.success');`

*use this in your controller `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang;`

In your case like this: `return back()->with('status', Lang::get('messages.success'));`

An example of `messages.php` would be:

```
return [

    'success' => 'your success message.',
    'success1' => 'your success1 message.'
];
```